# How to hide status bar on demand?

Tags: ios, swift

I have some drops downs in a view controller and when they drop down I'd like to hide the status bar. I know this is how we do it in a vc:

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

But what about from inside a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an instance variable to your view controller class `var statusBarHidden = false` and override `prefersStatusBarHidden` to return `statusBarHidden`.

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return statusBarHidden
}
```

Then any time you need to hide/show the status bar, use the following code snippet:

```
statusBarHidden = !statusBarHidden
setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```

Comment: `setStatusBarHidden` is deprecated in ios 9.0

Comment: The second method is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! I removed the first method since it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's `UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden=true` but it's off the top of my head.