# Change operator time and battery level

Tags: ios

In Swift is there any chance to change operator name, time, and battery level in app?

I want to change them temporarily in my joke app.

If Apple does not allow it how can I do it early?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea whether Apple allows an app to show a fake status bar or not but you can easily do it while your app is running. You can't show a fake status bar when your app isn't running.

To show a fake status bar in your own app, simply hide the real status bar and show your fake one at the top of your app's view.

See [the following for information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36364600/how-to-hide-status-bar-on-demand) on hiding the status bar.